# is it possible to switch languages on a page manually?

Tags: localisation

I have a Civi install that needs to support multiple languages for a few forms. The site itself is not multilingual, so I've not enabled the option to inherit the CMS language, and the language-switching should be available to anonymous users, so I can't make use of the language preference field. I'd like to be able to allow the visitor to switch the language dynamically -- presumably with a URL parameter. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

This is done by appending &lcMessages=fr_FR to the URL (where fr_FR is the desired language code).

When multiple languages are enabled, there is a language switcher block that becomes enabled. What threw me off is that in Joomla that is a fixed block in the admin interface left sidebar -- but is not available to the public side of the site. In Drupal it is a block, which is more configurable. But all the language switcher does is reload the current URL with the appropriate language value.